# How to use itemAfter or itemBefore in PagingSource LoadResult Page Paging 3

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager2, android-paging, android-paging-3

Hey I am working on unlimited data with **Viewpager 2** and **Paging 3 library**. I successfully created the logic to create unlimited pages by the help of paging source. I am swiping single pages by buttons in both direction.

Video Link to watch :- [Youtube Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-2PsmQRUu4)

Github Source: - [ViewPager Repository](https://github.com/vivek-modi/ViewPagerExample)

**Problem what I am getting**

When i click slowly on previous button it swipe single page, but if i click quickly multiple times on previous button it start scrolling more than we click and it's not stopping until we click on viewpager. It's kind of race condition.

I asked in issue tracker, they suggested me to use **itemBefore** and **itemAfter**
[IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173343982). I implemented this, but i failed to achieve good outcome.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.viewModels
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.lifecycle.lifecycleScope
import com.example.viewpagerexample.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.collectLatest
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<ViewPagerViewModel>()
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter()
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.dataList.collectLatest {
                adapter.submitData(it)
            }
        }
        binding.viewpager.adapter = adapter

        binding.next.setOnClickListener {
            binding.viewpager.setCurrentItem(binding.viewpager.currentItem.plus(1), true)
        }

        binding.previous.setOnClickListener {
            binding.viewpager.setCurrentItem(binding.viewpager.currentItem.minus(1), true)
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerDataSource.kt**

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample

import android.util.Log
import java.util.*

class ViewPagerDataSource(
    private val pageSize: Int,
    private val currentDate: Date
) {
    fun loadDataSource(pageNumber: Int): List<Date> {
        val dates = mutableListOf<Date>()
        val startingDate = startingDate(pageNumber)
        val tempCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        tempCalendar.time = startingDate

        Log.e("loadData startingDate", "" + startingDate)

        var index = 0;
        while (index++ < pageSize) {
            dates.add(tempCalendar.time)
            tempCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        }
        return dates
    }

    private fun startingDate(pageNumber: Int): Date {
        Calendar.getInstance().let {
            it.time = currentDate
            it.add(Calendar.DATE, (pageNumber * pageSize) + pageSize)
            return it.time
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerPagingSource.kt**

This is my paging source and i don't get how to use **itembefore** and **itemAfter** in my condition. Also I didn't get **getRefreshKey** what is the use of this? If i pass null is it fine for that or what else do I need to pass.

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample

import androidx.paging.PagingSource
import androidx.paging.PagingState
import java.io.IOException
import java.util.*

class ViewPagerPagingSource(
    private val dataSource: ViewPagerDataSource
) : PagingSource<Int, Date>() {

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, Date> {
        val position = params.key ?: 0

        return try {
            val data = dataSource.loadDataSource(position)
            LoadResult.Page(
                data = data,
                prevKey = if (data.isEmpty()) null else position - 1,
                nextKey = if (data.isEmpty()) null else position + 1,
                itemsBefore = LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED,
                itemsAfter = LoadResult.Page.COUNT_UNDEFINED
            )
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            LoadResult.Error(exception)
        }
    }

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, Date>): Int? {
        return null
    }
}
```

**ViewPagerViewModel.kt**

```
package com.example.viewpagerexample

import android.app.Application
import androidx.lifecycle.AndroidViewModel
import androidx.paging.Pager
import androidx.paging.PagingConfig
import java.util.*

class ViewPagerViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val dataSource = ViewPagerDataSource(10, currentDate())

    val dataList =
        Pager(config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 10,
            enablePlaceholders = true
        ), pagingSourceFactory = {
            ViewPagerPagingSource(dataSource)
        }).flow

    private fun currentDate(): Date {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        return calendar.time
    }
}
```

Adapter and Holder are attached in Github Link please find if you need them.

**build.Gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.viewpagerexample"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'

    implementation "androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0"

    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime-ktx:3.0.1"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6'

    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't dig too deep, I have no idea why this problem appears only if you programmatically scroll to previous page. As I know only reason to use itemBefore and itemAfter is when you want to show placeholders while data is still loading and you know exact data length. Сoncerning getRefreshKey() method - that is what I found in official docs -

> if items are loaded based on integer position keys, you can return
> state.anchorPosition

So I can't explain why this problem happens, but I can give you piece of code that will probably solve it:

```
 binding.previous.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.viewpager.scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                binding.viewpager.setCurrentItem(binding.viewpager.currentItem.minus(1), true)
            }
        }
```

I went into the source code of ViewPager2 and noticed that regarding scrolling there are such calls as `view.post()`, respectively, this is due to multithreading. As I said, I didn't go deep into the problem, instead I just found a constant with which the current scroll state of the ViewPager2 is compared(SCROLL_STATE_IDLE - indicates that the ViewPager2 is in an idle, settled state).

**EDIT:**
to make it, for example, 10 days forward and infinite backwards you should do this:

```
class ViewPagerViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    private val dataSource = ViewPagerDataSource(5, currentDate(), endDate())

    val dataList =
        Pager(config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 5,
            enablePlaceholders = false,
            jumpThreshold =5
        ), pagingSourceFactory = {
            ViewPagerPagingSource(dataSource)
        }).flow

    private fun currentDate(): Date {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        return calendar.time
    }

    private fun endDate(): Date {
        val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        calendar.time = Date()
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 10)
        return calendar.time
    }
}
```

and then -

```
class ViewPagerDataSource(
    private val pageSize: Int,
    private val currentDate: Date,
    private val endDate: Date
) {
    fun loadDataSource(pageNumber: Int): List<Date> {
        val dates = mutableListOf<Date>()
        val startingDate = startingDate(pageNumber)
        if (startingDate.after(endDate)){
            return dates
        }
        val tempCalendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        tempCalendar.time = startingDate

        Log.e("loadData startingDate", "" + startingDate)

        var index = 0;
        while (index++ < pageSize) {
            dates.add(tempCalendar.time)
            tempCalendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1)
        }
        return dates
    }

    private fun startingDate(pageNumber: Int): Date {
        Calendar.getInstance().let {
            it.time = currentDate
            it.add(Calendar.DATE, (pageNumber * pageSize) + pageSize)
            return it.time
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @AlexRmcf it solved my problem. Thanks a million. So` getRefreshKey()` do i need to pass something or just pass null.

Comment: in your case just return state.anchorPosition

Comment: once again thanks a million. You are life saver man @AlexRmcf. I need small help again **ViewPagerDataSource** can you see that file. Inside that I am creating unlimited date in both side. How can I stop to creating a list at particular date. If I pass any **endLimitDate** my list will not create after **endLimitDate** but create unlimit date before that date. I am stuck on that as well can you tell me how can i achieve that as well. Thanks

Comment: Yes you can do that. Just do something like this - add private val endLimitDate : Date to ViewPagerDataSource() constructor. Then in your loadDataSource(pageNumber: Int) do something like this -  if (startingDate.after(endLimitDate )){
            return dates
        } 
where dates is just empty list of Date
and that is probably all

Comment: if I pass endLimit date to as current date **07/10/2021** so the list would return all previous date like **07/10/2021**,**06/10/2021**,**05/10/2021...** Till unlimited previous date. Is it right ?

Comment: @vivekmodi, see edited answer

Answer (score 2):

That happened because you are using Data binding with smooth scrolling:
smooth scrolling take time to perform and when you try to click very fast ,binding take next page while scrolling and start infinite scrolling:

there is two solution :

1 - making smooth scrolling false :

```
binding.viewpager.setCurrentItem(binding.viewpager.currentItem.plus(1), false)
```

2- separate binding from scrolling code :

```
val nextPage = binding.viewpager.currentItem+1
binding.viewpager.setCurrentItem(nextPage, true)
```

Comment: thanks for your help. This is not a data binding issue. If you use synthetic the issue will be same. Most Important thing is i cannot remove smooth scroll from there.